# Is there a common font format for Jasper on linux and windows to produce pdf?

Tags: java, linux, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am working on jasper reports to produce PDF file.

I have problem that is Font format exception when I run program which generates PDF on linux OS machine. I have used Times new roman font format for jasper file and linux OS does not support Times new roman, can anyone suggest me common font format for linux and windows OS to create jasper file .

Comment: You need to add your own font files to your app and use those fonts, if you want to be independent from the fonts provided by OS.

Comment: I assume you used google first - I just did, and found http://lists.apple.com/archives/webobjects-dev/2011/Sep/msg00192.html for "jasper fonts cross-OS", which links to instructions on https://github.com/wocommunity/wonder/commit/3252276338c323256065be95ad1f5d3a5b95fc2c -- did that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java defines the following five [logical font](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html) families:

- Dialog
- DialogInput
- Monospaced
- Serif
- SansSerif

This means that these fonts are always available in java runtime, however they are not actual font libraries but mapped by java to some font installed on system. Hence using any of these font will not cause any error in java.

However, you are exporting to pdf that instead have what is called [Standard Type 1 fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344944/what-s-difference-between-font-is-embedd-fonts-and-nonembedd-font/27345103#27345103) as you can see there is no match and iText (the lib creating the pdf) will use if not defined the default font Helvetica.

The **conclusion** is that while using a logical font, which would not throw an errors this could lead to **report inconsistency** in pdf (using another font).

The **solution** in jasper-reports is to use **font-extensions**

Comment: Thank you very much Petter Friberg . its solved my problem .

Comment: Thanks all for your kind support